# ScrollablePositionedList is rebuilt after inserting new item to zero index of the list

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to write a chat room so I use reversed  `ScrollablePositionedList` for showing the chats when a chat is received I insert it to the zero index and after that whole `ScrollablePositionedList` is rebuilt. Is there any way preventing `ScrollablePositionedList` from reloading?

```
ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
  reverse: true,
  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: _chatController.chats.length,
  itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
  itemPositionsListener: itemPositionsListener,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ShowChatWidget();
  },
),
```

adding new chat:

```
if (res.resultCode == 200) {
  chats.insert(0,res.result!)
  chats.refresh();
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `chats`?

Comment: image, sound and text

Comment: I mean the object 'chats', is it a `List`?

Comment: yes its type is list

Comment: I assume you used the package 'scrollable_positioned_list', since Flutter doesn't have that type of widget. Am I correct that the only reason for this is to display the most recent messages at the bottom? Furthermore, what is the issue with reloading exactly?

Comment: yes its a package and i use it because when some one select the replay message i should scroll to the index of the selected replay message.my problem is when a new message is received i have to show it at the end of the list so i insert it at the zero index of the list ,after that because the list index is changed whole list items reload so image and sound widget reload

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you fix this problem by adding a key to ListView .builder() `PageStorageKey(T value)` which will prevent the list from rebuilding.

```
ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
  key: const PageStorageKey<String>('add_key_name'),
  reverse: true,
  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: _chatController.chats.length,
  itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
  itemPositionsListener: itemPositionsListener,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ShowChatWidget();
  },
),
```

Comment: i added key to the  `scrollablePositionedList ` but Unfortunately it does not work and the problem still exists

Comment: Hey, can you share the full code of the chats screen? And did you try with any state management pattern

Comment: cause of company privacy i cant send the code but the structure is simple whenever a chat is receive i haded to obs list and list  will be update in fact i use `obx ` for handling the state management actually `ScrollablePositionedList` wrap white `obx` widget

Comment: You can try with BouncingScrollPhysics()

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by using ListView.custom:

```
 ListView.custom(
          childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return MYWIDGET,
            childCount: items.length,
            findChildIndexCallback: (Key key) {
              final ValueKey<String> valueKey = key as ValueKey<String>;
              final String data = valueKey.value;
              return items.indexOf(data);
            }
          ),
        ),
      ),
```